# Breeze JS client side with .net 3.5 possible?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, breeze, single-page-application

Breeze JS is only supported in net 4 or 4.5? 
can i use breeze only in client side and my server is .net 3.5. 
I am using ADO.net as datalayer and not using Entity Framework.
Will I miss any of the features of Breeze JS if i use .net 3.5?
 I had seen many articles with Breeze JS and MVC. 
How this can be done with .net 3.5?
 Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To support the BreezeJS client, the server should do 3 things:

1. Provide [metadata](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/metadata-schema) to the client
2. Interpret [queries](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/query-examples) from the client, and respond with data
3. [Save changes](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/saving-changes) that come in from the client

All three of these are provided in .NET 4.5 by the `EFContextProvider` (for Entity Framework) and `NHContext` (for NHibernate).  You will need to find a way to implement these for your solution.

**Metadata:** Can be [written by hand](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/metadata-by-hand) or even [generated by EF](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/ef-design-tool) at design time (even if you aren't using EF at runtime).  If you just need metadata for your project, you don't need a general-purpose metadata generation tool.

**Queries:** Can be as simple or complicated as your application requires.  Filtering on a single field, sorting, and `skip` and `take` for pagination, may be sufficient.  You can implement most everything as [parameterized queries](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/querying-depth#withParameters), so you don't need to parse the URL.  This limits the types of queries that you can perform from the client, but it may be all you need.

**Saves:** Breeze "save bundles" are an array of entities, each with an EntityAspect than tells you what type of change it is (Added, Modified, Deleted) and what fields changed.
You will need to apply these operations to the database.  Note that the order in which they are applied is important 
(parent records must be added before child records, child records must be deleted before parent records).

In EFContextProvider, a lot of this work was done by EF itself.  In NHContext, the queries are mostly taken care of using NH LINQ, 
but the metadata generation and save handling had to be written in Breeze.ContextProvider.NH.  You can look at the [code on github](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net) for inspiration.
Also look at the [NoDB](http://www.getbreezenow.com/samples/nodb) sample, which doesn't use EF or NH.

Please let us know what you come up with.  Breeze without an ORM is an interesting topic.